# Which one layout is adding - Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen

I created two resource `layout`(`layout` , `layout-large`) .

How can I find in my code(programmatically) that which one `layout` is adding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you created two resource folder, one solution is to create these folder for values too. Then for values folder add this:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="isLarge">false</bool>
</resources>
```

and in your values-large folder:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="isLarge">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Then in your activity:

```
boolean isLarge = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isLarge);
if (isLarge) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: @ A. Badakhshan. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tag attribute:

`android:tag="layout-large`"

and then use it in your code:

```
String tag = view.getTag();
if ("layout-large".equals(tag)) {
    //do something
} else if ("layout".equals(tag)) {
    //do something different
}
```

Comment: How can I use from it ?

Comment: I've updated my answer but I'm not sure if it answers your question.

Comment: The resources solutions is more reliable and cleaner